# Trigger backbone change event without blur / lost focus on an input field

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, onchange

I have an input field that gets populated by a hardware scanner.

I need backbone to fire the change event when the input field is populated, but without the blur event occurring.  Is this possible with backbone, or will the change event only fire after the blur event has occurred?

Backbone Events Declaration:

```
    events: {
        // On destination populate set destination and focus on location
        "change #destination" : "destinationscan",
        // On Location populate set location and focus on crate
        "change #location" : "locationscan",
        // On crate populate send data.
        "change #name" : "cratescan"
    },
```

HTML:

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Crate Name..." required value="" />
            <div id="locationtaholder">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type a location..." required id="location" /><img id="clearlocation" src="img/clear.png" alt="Clear Location" title="Clear Location" class="item-hidden" />
                <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu"></ul>

            </div>
            <div id="destinationtaholder">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type a destination..." id="destination" /><img id="cleardestination"   src="img/clear.png" alt="Clear Destination" title="Clear Destination" class="item-hidden" />
                <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu"></ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me whats the problem. Your "hardware scanner" does not fire all expected events or does it fire events you don't want. [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you want to avoid the blur? Please add some infos how that "_hardware_ scanner" interacts with your browser: e.g. does it emulate a keyboard like some bar code scanners?

Comment: The hardward scanner populates the input field like a paste would, but without the keypress events.  It does not blur the input box and I need to process the data that arrives in the input field as soon as it is scanned, so cannot use the change event as that only fires on blur.

Comment: I see. There's a `change` event, but probably for incomplete strings too. Is this true? Can you add another field the scanner may fill with any dummy data? You may use this chnage to detect filling the other fields is done.

Comment: So how does your hardware scanner/code that updates the input inform backbone/jquery whatever it has changed? These libraries are based on their own event system + browsers event system. They aren't aware of your scanner. This is not a problem with backbone, it seems to be a problem with your hardware scanner. It needs to expose an API which informs about the arrival of new data... where you can trigger a backbone/jquery event to notify these libs about the change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event in backbone is Jquery event. So if you dont want trigger blur to apply the change you can direct trigger change event after populated input:

```
$('selector').change();
$('selector').trigger("change");
```

Comment: How do I capture the populate event?

Comment: It's vary, just base on your context. The simple way to be check key up, down in your input field.

Comment: But keyup / keydown wont fire as the input is populated by a hardward scanner input.